# There is two button, once click on the button the name of the button will render inside the id

Tags: reactjs

Hi guys help me on this i am stuck for a project.

After the button click, the page should look like:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg64f.jpg)

Once click on the button the bellow text will call the color name just like the image

```
class ColorChange extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = 
}

  render() {
    
    return null;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ''
  }

  onDocumentClick = (event) => {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      this.setState({ text: event.target.textContent })
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.onDocumentClick)
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.onDocumentClick)
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.children}
      <Tooltip text={this.state.text}/>
    </div>
  }
}

  <button id="btnGreen">Green</button>
  <button id="btnRed">Red</button>

document.getElementById("button2").click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
import { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ""
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "green",
            color: "white",
            cursor: "pointer"
          }}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ text: "GREEN" })}
        >
          GREEN
        </button>
        <button
          style={{ backgroundColor: "red", color: "white", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ text: "RED" })}
        >
          RED
        </button>
        <br />
        COLOR: {this.state.text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-rain-0kibj) for a live working example.